# in a Python regex matchobj, how to do a substring match, and assign the match to a variable?

Tags: python, regex

Given this re.sub and 'replace' function - thanks, Ignacio, for the pointer! - I am able to replace all matches in my very long text blob with the string '*** NONSENSE ***' - so far, so good!

Along the way, I'd like to find the ***substring*** within the matchobj, calling it '**findkey**', so I can do additional work with it...

How do to this?

```
data = re.sub('(:::[A-Z,a-z,:]+:::)', replace, data)

def replace(matchobj):
 if matchobj.group(0) != '':

  # this seems to work:
  tag = matchobj.group(1)

  # but this doesn't:
  findkey = re.search(':::([A-Z,a-z]+):::', tag)

  return '********************  NONSENSE  ********************'

 else:
  return ''
```

Comment: This code works exactly as I expect it to. What do you want `findkey` to contain? Right now it contains a match object.

Comment: Note that I'm trying to use findkey for a match _within_ tag. It's a sub-group match, effectively.

Comment: ok, noted. This still works as expected. Are you saying that you want `'findkey'` to _contain a substring_? Right now, it contains a match object that contains the match and all sub-group matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  You can match the inner part as part of the initial sub call.

```
import re

data = ":::::::::::BLAH:::::::::, ::::::::MORE:::::::"

def replace(matchobj):
  # this seems to work:
  tag = matchobj.group(0)
  findkey = matchobj.group(1)

  print findkey

  return '********************  NONSENSE  ********************'


data = re.sub(r':::(?P<inner>[A-Z,a-z]+):::', replace, data)

print data
```

returns the following

```
BLAH
MORE
::::::::********************  NONSENSE  ********************::::::, :::::********************  NONSENSE  ********************::::
```

Comment: thanks, milkypostman - this is really spot on in my case. I have been trying to 'jibe' my concepts of multiple pattern match to python code. That was the secret sauce.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
findkey = re.search(':::([A-Z,a-z]+):::', tag).group()
```

Note the group() and also [this document](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html) can help.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Senthil, that was great - I didn't know how to use the group() method.

I can now see findkey in a log entry, but now have a new problem; cannot use it as a variable, as in: 

`result = plpy.execute(plan3, [ fieldid ] )`

Comment: I did not get that part. You cannot use string as a variable. You variables are only labels, you can assign the output string to your variable. HTH.